Theme/Icons changed, 22.04LTS
I am using Ubuntu 22.04LTS; I had Pro enabled at the time (disabled now). Yesterday (5/9/2024), I realized that my system icons changed, and some display aspects of stock applications - to some high-contrast "theme" without me doing anything that I know of.
I dug around trying to find some automatic update that may have changed something, to no avail.  I looked at Settings/Appearance and Gnome-Tweaks, tried changing theme away from and back to stock Yaru, nothing seemed to alter these icons.
I even updated one of my Virtual Box 22.04LTS instances to try to recreate it but it looks perfectly normal, and I still have no idea what's wrong.
I tried reinstalling ubuntu-gnome-desktop and the yaru-theme-* packages, no effect.
Some screen caps showing icons:
Some icons:

Mix of normal and b/w icons:


I am rather embarrassed to say, this one is on me.
I had the accessibility menu in the top-right panel for quick access to zoom for developer reasons.  I hardly ever use it and somehow I triggered High-Contrast mode, which shows all the gnome system application icons in their stark high-contrast views.
